# Print ParseObject content

Tags: java, android, json, parse-platform

perhaps this is a silly question but, I'm trying just to print ALL the content (not just one field) of a ParseObject (Parse platform). But I didn't found anything about that, either the API, forums or here.

toString method it's not overridden inside the API, and there is no "toJsonString" or "toJson" or "getValues" nothing like that.

Any suggestion?

Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no methods provided by `Parse' to do that. But you can use [keySet()](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseObject.html#keySet()) method to implement that. It's quick sample to give your direction.

```
    try {
        TestParse parseObject = ParseObject.createWithoutData(TestParse.class, "tjkbdde0B1");
        JSONObject jsonObject = parseObjectToJson(parseObject);
        Log.d("TAG", jsonObject.toString(4));
    } catch (ParseException | JSONException e) {
        Log.e("TAG", e.getMessage());
    }
```

Method to convert to JSON object

```
private JSONObject parseObjectToJson(ParseObject parseObject) throws ParseException, JSONException {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    parseObject.fetchIfNeeded();
    Set<String> keys = parseObject.keySet();
    for (String key : keys) {
        Object objectValue = parseObject.get(key);
        if (objectValue instanceof ParseObject) {
            jsonObject.put(key, parseObjectToJson(parseObject.getParseObject(key)));
            // keep in mind about "pointer" to it self, will gain stackoverlow
        } else if (objectValue instanceof ParseRelation) {
            // handle relation
        } else {
            jsonObject.put(key, objectValue.toString());
        }
    }
    return jsonObject;
}
```

You can extend it to care about other possible types at `Parse`, all in your hands.

Comment: Yeah your right. There is not method to print, strange but true. I'll set your response as valid. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
myParseObject.getJSONObject(myKey).toString();
```

[ParseObject `getJSONObject` method](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseObject.html#getJSONObject(java.lang.String))

[JSONObject `toString` method](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#toString())

Comment: Sorry I've edit the answer, it's ALL fields, get the string json representation and print it.

Comment: @MarcoHC I think the `toString` method _does_ return a string in which all the fields are included. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Nop, that prints just the object id as I tried to clarify before "toString method it's not overridden inside the API". Thanks!

Comment: @MarcoHC and you're doing the `getJSONObject()` call **before** using `toString` right? I don't doubt you, but if you could edit your question to include some sample code (e.g. a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)), it would help a lot.

Comment: I meant print all the json object, the root node, not only a part of it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From `ParseObject`, you'll have to get each field individually. Depending on the datatype, use something like `myParseObject.getString("myStringFieldName")` or `myParseObject.getInt("myIntFieldName")`. Then, once you have that value, you can do whatever you like with it.

Comment: Sorry I've edit the answer, it's ALL fields, get the string json representation and print it.

Answer (score 0):

https://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/master/Parse.Object.html#toJSON

Example:

```
console.log( feature.toJSON() );
```